# Hyperledger Fabric OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to create a channel using Hyperledger Fabric, but I encountered the following error: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./scripts/setAnchorPeer.sh": stat ./scripts/setAnchorPeer.sh: no such file or directory: unknown

I've encountered an issue while attempting to individually run containers for better modularity and control in the Hyperledger Fabric test network setup. The specific error is related to a missing directory inside the container when running a script. Interestingly, this issue arises only when calling a second script within the process.

I've explored potential solutions, including attempting to mount the directory explicitly when running containers individually, but this hasn't resolved the issue. The scenario involves running a script that calls another script, and it's at the point of invoking this second script that the error occurs.

I'm seeking insights into what might be causing this discrepancy between running containers individually versus using Docker Compose, especially when scripts are involved. The goal is to gain greater control and modularity by running the containers separately. Has anyone faced a similar challenge in the context of deploying a Hyperledger Fabric test network? Are there specific configurations or considerations I should be mindful of when opting for individual container execution as opposed to using Docker Compose? Your guidance and assistance in resolving this matter are greatly appreciated.